# How to make structure where container's element can call containers only one private function

Tags: c++, pointers, callback, containers, friend

I want to make structure where *container element* can give **callbacks** to *containers*, but I dont want to make it be `public`. How should I make it ? I'm not guaranteed, maybe I need statically give container's *private functions* adress to element or use somehow `friend`? By the way *element* should "see" others container's private functions.

E.g. `class Cont` stores `class Elem`. `Cont` has *private function* `void callback();`. `Elem` knows in which `Cont` he is, and can call *callback function*. No one outside `Cont` can use *callbacks function*.

Comment: Please write comment, if you downvote question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `Elem` constructor, you could have an argument to the callback (using e.g. [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) or similar), and have the `Elem` class store it. Then when the callback needs to be called, just call it.

You could also create a "setter" function in `Elem` to set the callback.

---

Full example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

class Elem
{
private:
    int value_;
    std::function<void(const std::string&)> callback_;

public:
    Elem(int v, std::function<void(const std::string&)> cb)
        : value_{v}, callback_{cb}
    {}

    void some_function() const
    {
        callback_("Elem with value " + std::to_string(value_));
    }
};

class Cont
{
private:
    std::vector<Elem> elements_;

    void private_function(const std::string& s)
    {
        std::cout << "In private function: " << s << '\n';
    }

public:
    void add_value(const int v)
    {
        elements_.push_back(Elem(v, std::bind(&Cont::private_function, this, std::placeholders::_1)));
    }

    std::vector<Elem>::const_iterator begin() const
    {
        return std::begin(elements_);
    }

    std::vector<Elem>::const_iterator end() const
    {
        return std::end(elements_);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Cont c;

    // Add some elements
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i)
        c.add_value(i);

    // Call callback function
    for (const auto& e : c)
        e.some_function();
}
```

Output:

```
In private function: Elem with value 1
In private function: Elem with value 2
In private function: Elem with value 3
In private function: Elem with value 4
In private function: Elem with value 5
In private function: Elem with value 6
In private function: Elem with value 7
In private function: Elem with value 8
In private function: Elem with value 9
In private function: Elem with value 10
```

[See it in action.](http://ideone.com/lh0NlD)

In the code above, the private function `Cont::private_function` is totally unknown to the `Elem` class, and can't be called directly. However, we can pass it to the `Elem` class using arguments, and then call it from inside the `Elem` class without exposing the private function at all.

Comment: I need to store `class Cont` private function adress in `class Elem` statically and store `Cont c1` adress in `Elem e1` dinamically. How to assign `class Cont` private function's adress to `class Elem`'s static variable once when program starts ?

Comment: @Vinigas Added a simple example of what I mean.

Comment: @Joachim_Pileborg So callback_ gonna store specific container's adress and function to it ? What `std::placeholders::_1"` is for ?

Comment: @Vinigas The `std::placeholders::_1` is because the function I pass to [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) takes one argument, and `std::bind` needs a placeholder where that argument should be.

Comment: @Vinigas And exactly what `std::bind` returns, or `std::function` stores doesn't matter, all that's matter is that by "calling" `callback_` in the `Elem` class you call the function passed to the `std::bind` call.